# Swift: UIBarButtonItem setting accessibility identifier programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to set accessibility identifier. I look into this sample:

```
myBarButton.accessibilityIdentifier = @"I am a test button!";
```

But I don't get the accessibilityIdentifier in swift.

Any of you knows how can I set the accessibilityIdentifier in swift?

Comment: Did you make it `isAccessibilityElement = true`?

Answer (score 1):

`UIBarButtonItem` does not implement `UIAccessibilityIdentification`, so setting `accessibilityIdentifier` doesn't work.

Instead try

```
myBarButton.accessibilityLabel = "I am a test button!"
```

Comment: I'm having this issue as well and every issue I see says that `UIBarButtonItem` does not conform to `UIAccessibilityIdentification` but it is! Look at the documentation "conforms to" part [UIBarButtonItem](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarbuttonitem)

Comment: `UIBarButtonItem` does indeed conform to `UIAccessibilityIdentification` because it inherits `UIBarItem` which conforms to the protocol.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this

```
myBarButtonItem.isAccessibilityElement = true
myBarButtonItem.accessibilityLabel = "I am a test button!"
myBarButtonItem.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraits
```